# How to get Elasticsearch Key/Values in Aggregation Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get more than just a key with Elasticsearch aggregation buckets?  For example if I'm getting countries, I can get the keys as follows:

```
"aggregations": {
  "countries": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "china",
           "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
           "key": "italy",
           "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
           "key": "japan",
           "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
           "key": "united-kingdom",
           "doc_count": 1
        }
     ]
  }
```

}

But I would also like get some associated data for example the country name not as a slug: (e.g. China, Italy, Japan, United Kingdom).

Now the mapping is like this

```
PUT tester/listing/_mapping
{
  "properties": {

    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    }, 

    "countries": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "doc_values": true
    }

  }
}
```

And the records are indexed as follows:

```
POST tester/listing/1
{

  "title": "First Listing",
  "countries": ["spain", "italy"]

}

POST tester/listing/2
{

  "title": "Second Listing",
  "countries": ["japan", "united-kingdom"]

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly you want ? What additional data are you looking for...

Comment: @VineethMohan I need to populate a select dropdown based on the aggregation.  Something like: <select><option name="country" value="united-kingdom">United Kingdom</option>...</select>.  I can only get the value (united-kingdom) from the bucket, but I would like to set up the mapping so that I could include the name (United Kingdom) and get both united-kingdom and United Kingdom in the aggregation without having to do another request.

Comment: What i dont understand is where is the data which maps united-kingdom to "United Kingdom" ?

Comment: @VineethMohan Sorry, it's unclear.  That's what I'm trying to figure out. A way to map and index both the slug (united-kingdom) and the label (United Kingdom), so that they would both be accessible in the filter bucket.  But I don't know if that's even possible.